# How to set any header in cakePHP 2.6 Controller Test

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.6

I have a Controller function, that expects the header 'X-Bla-Bla' from my JSON call. I catch the header with this:

```
$this->request->header('X-Bla-Bla')
```

Now I want to write a test for this but I can't send headers.

My test looks like this:

```
    $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    $url = Router::url(array('api' => true, 'controller' => 'test', 'action' => 'index'));
    $options = array(
        'return' => 'contents',
    );
    $result = $this->testAction($url, $options);
    $this->assertNotEmpty($result);
```

**How can I send the header?**

If not, how can I still test my function?

Comment: Hint: `X-Requested-With` is a header too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set header this way in the test:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_BLA_BLA'] = 'abc';
```

before calling `testAction()`, then your controller's action will be able to read `'abc'` with expression:

```
$this->request->header('X-Bla-Bla')
```